# BMI Category is qualitative or quantitative

Tags: categorical-data, variable

I know for sure that BMI(Body Mass Index) is a quantitative variable as it is a continuous variable. But is that BMI Category derived from the BMI a qualitative variable or a quantitative variable? (Underweight, Normal Weight, Overweight. Thanks

Comment: It is considered to be in this hybrid category called ordinal. Depending on what you’re doing, binning into these categories may discard useful information. What are you trying to do with BMI?

Comment: I am trying to make a contingency table with other categories, but I need to make sure that BMI Category is a quantitative variable.

Comment: Why do you want to make such a contingency table ? What is your research question ?

Comment: I want to make a two-way contingency table with BMI Category and Favorite Ice Cream flavor to know if that a certain ice cream flavor can cause overweight.

Comment: First, you can't establish causation with any kind of observational study.  Second, why don't you use a regression model, with BMI as the outcome and ice cream flavour as the independent variable ? Categorising your data will lead to massive data loss.

Answer (score 6):

Usually we think of this type of data as a special form of categorical data called "ordinal", that is, ordered-categorical. This is because there is a natural ordering in the data: Underweight < Normal < Overweight.

While it is sometimes useful to create categories such as these, there is a great loss of information by doing so.

Edit:  Based on comments in the question, it would be a good idea to consider a regression based model, where you do not categorise BMI but rather use it as the outcome/response. Since you seem to have a just one independent variable, which is categorical, this would be a one-way ANOVA.

Comment: This ANOVA ends up being just a vanilla t-test!

Comment: @Dave but we don't know how many categories the IV has. Either way, it's better than categorizing the DV imho

Comment: I read the comment as being between two ice cream flavors. Looking at it again, I am not sure how. Yes, if there are 3+ flavors, then it isn't a t-test.

Comment: @Dave I agree it's a bit unclear but I think it's good as  pedagogical device to think about regression.